# Local XML file is not parsing?

Tags: objective-c, xml, ios4, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

In My iphone application i have two XML files. I can parse **one.xml** eailsy but i am not able to parse **two.xml**
I have use the same tags for both files. In parsing **two.xml** the method didStatrElement is not calling.
Why is  thereany problem in file. If how to resolve it. Plz anyone can help me regarding this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Pls, post both of you xml-files

Comment: without showing us the structure of xml, or xml files, how can you expect us to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,your's issue maybe caused by several reasons, I will list what I know:
1.NSXMLParserDelegate .You should set one.xml's delegate nil when you ready to parse two.xml.
2.Use different array store data.
3.I think NSOperationQueue can be used.
If I was wrong, welcome your correction.
Best regards.